# How to develop a cross-browser, simplified photo uploader

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, file-upload, html, photo

similar to [what is shown here](http://www.position-absolute.com/news/in-video-mozilla-show-the-future-of-web-file-uploading/).

I don't need total image editing... only rotation, maybe cropping. But the user being able to drag'n drop a photo and then minor editing is what I'm after. I'm sure there's a jQuery plugin for something like it. (preferably not an HTML5 solution)

However, I've refrained from using uploaders that use an ajax uploader, for this reason:

[In my site](http://www.apoads.com), users can create ads to sell their goods. They can attach photos to show off those goods. If I allow ajax photo upload and then the user does not actually save the ad, how do I handle removal of photos that were ajax uploaded but no longer needed?

Or, what's stopping someone from ajax uploading multiple photos over and over, taking up space on my server?

I'm thinking some kind of daily process to nuke the stale photos, but that's a bit cludgy imo. I'm open to suggestions though. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gears](http://gears.google.com/). Few years ago I saw a Java applet which did that. I don't think there is a JS only solution.

[Gears example](http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/drag-and-drop-file-upload-with-google-gears)

Comment: Thanks for that. How about a way to only be able to rotate image before upload? I guess that's still client side... ugh, wish HTML5 was the standard now!

Comment: Well... About rotate: you can rotate with js but i guess only in 45° steps (in order to be cross browser).

However, you can try either a flash thing or serverside processing.